# how can I Create a function (countMs) that takes a string text and returns the number of letters'm'in it(both uppercase and lowercase)using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to solve this problem
Create a function (countMs) that takes a string text and returns the number of letters 'm' in it (both uppercase and lowercase).
Hint 1
.Create a variable count
.Create a for of loop where you will iterate over each character of text
At every iteration check whether the current character is 'm' or 'M': if it's true, increase the
count by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to try it with [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
const str = "asd9089m1mmgrfsmbidjvmMmMmmamsdf1mr38jfMMmadfafvaMMmamsdmamas134m3mfMMmeasfmasmfamMmasmdm";
// Matches "m"
// i flag = case insensitive
// g flag = global, do not exit after the first match is found.
const totalMs = str.match(/m/ig).length;

console.log({ totalMs });
```

Otherwise do as per the Hint, which is to iterate each character. A string is basically an array of character, and you can use [loop iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to count if the character matches `M` or `m`.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling im doing someone's homework for them :)

```js
function countMs(input) {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let c = input.charAt(i);
        if(c === 'M' || c === 'm') count++;
    }
    return count;

}
```

Comment: returns error
Function 'countMs' should return 1 if input contains one lowercase 'm'